# D3 donut chart function only works the first time it's called

Tags: javascript, function, d3.js, charts

I have created a function to make a donut chart with D3 and it works great the first time it is called. However, the subsequent times it is called the SVG elements it appends are empty and the paths are appended to the 1st chart. I am new to D3 so there is a good chance I am doing something bad in my function. There is no error message in the console. Please let me know if you see something strange. Thank you!!

Here is the function:

```
function donutChart (id, data, color) {

var donut = (function(one){ 
    console.log("Hello");
    var width = 400;
    var height = 400;
    var radius = 200;
    var greyColor = '#e8e8e8';
    var dataColor = '#1dafd3';
    var red
    var colors = d3.scaleOrdinal([color, greyColor]);
    var piedata = [{
            name: "one", value: data
        }, {
            name: "two", value: (1 - data)
        }];

    var arc = d3.arc().innerRadius(radius - 50).outerRadius(radius);

    var donutChart = d3.select(id).append('svg')
      .attr('width', width)
      .attr('height', height)
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (width - radius) + ',' + (height - radius) + ')');

    var pie = d3.pie()
      .sort(null)
      .value(function(piedata) { return piedata.value; });

    var arc_g = d3.select('svg g').selectAll('arc').data(pie(piedata)).enter()
        .append('g')
        .attr('class', 'slice');
    console.log()

    arc_g.append('path').attr("d",arc)
    .attr('fill', function(d, range) {
       return colors(range);
  })
  })();
};
```

Here is the function call, it works great the first time but not the second.

```
donutChart (songData.audio_features[0].danceability, "#1dafd3"); 
donutChart (songData.audio_features[0].acousticness, "#1dafd3");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that each time the function is called, you append a new SVG element with this line:

```
var donutChart = d3.select(id).append('svg')
```

as this selects the first element it finds with the ID and appends a new SVG element regardless.

Second problem occurs when you try to append arcs with this line

```
var arc_g = d3.select('svg g').selectAll('arc')
```

as again, 'select' will just find the first match in the DOM, which is your original SVG > G element, and select the arcs it can find there

Thirdly, the `.selectAll('arc')` won't find anything, as the existing elements are either 'path' or have class 'slice', so you need the selectAll to match either of those.

To rectify the problems:

```
//append the SVG on the first call, with a dummy data, and each subsequent call will use the existing element in the DOM
var donutChart = d3.select(id).selectAll('svg')
      .data([null])

donutChart = donutChart.enter().append('svg')
      .merge(donutChart)
      .attr('width', width)
      .attr('height', height)

var g = donutChart.append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (width - radius) + ',' + (height - radius) + ')');

    var pie = d3.pie()
      .sort(null)
      .value(function(piedata) { return piedata.value; });

//selectAll on class '.slice'
    var arc_g = g.selectAll('.slice')
        .data(pie(piedata))

//create new g and path elements on enter (ie if new), and then update d and color after a merge()
    arc_g = arc_g.enter()
        .append('g')
        .attr('class', 'slice')
        .append('path')
        .merge(arc_g)
        .attr("d",arc)
        .attr('fill', function(d, range) {
           return colors(range);
        })
```

For more info on merge, refer to: https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_merge